# metodo includes() javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Como podria hacer para chequear que un dato se incluya en una lista de listas?

codigo de abajo, quisiera que me diga "si", si es que lista x tiene entre sus elementos la variable g, que es [2,2]. A simple vista se ve que esta, pero no funciona el includes cuando se trata de listas de listas, creo

```
let x=[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
let g=[2,2]


  if (x.includes (g)){
    console.log("si")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero iteras en el array "x". Luego revisa si en cada elemento de cada array es igual a los elementos de "g" son iguales:

```
let checkEqual = (array1,array2) => {
  array1.forEach((elem) => {
     if (elem.every( (val,ind) => {val === array2[i]} ) ){
        console.log("Es igual");
    }         
  })
}
```

Comment: Para llamar la funcion, pon tus 2 arrays que quieres comparar. Ejem: checkEqual(x,g)

Answer (score 0):

También podrías utilizar [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) en lugar de un `forEach()`, ya que así evitas tener que recorrer todo el array puesto que `some()` se detendrá al encontrar al menos un valor [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy). Dentro del callback validas si alguno de los arrays que contiene `x` (`a`) es igual en valores a `g` (`b`).

```js
let x = [
  [1, 1],
  [2, 2],
  [3, 3]
]
let g = [3, 3]

function incluye(a, b) {
  return a.some(v => v.every((val, i) => val === b[i]))
}


if (incluye(x, g)) {
  console.log("si")
} else {
  console.log('No')
}
```

Comment: Borro mi respuesta que es muy parecida a la tuya y has respondido antes (no me había fijado ). Dejo como comentario la alternativa de cambiar `v.every((val, i) => val === b[i])` por `JSON.stringify(v) == JSON.stringify(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando el metodo join()

```js
let x=[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
let g=[2,2]
    
console.log(" Recorrer array x")
x.forEach( (r,i) => {
     if( r.join() == g.join() ){
        console.log( "existe", r.join(), " index "+i.toString() )
       }
})
```

[Link de apoyo](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples/blob/master/sheets/removingDuplicates/removingDuplicates.gs)